# how to make a webpage to get different image base on url enter

Tags: url, html

i know i could make 100 similar html pages for 100 images like this:

```
www.example.com/1.html
www.example.com/2.html
www.example.com/3.html
```

but how and what do i use to make it like this:

```
www.example.com/main.html?page=1
www.example.com/main.html?page=2
www.example.com/main.html?page=3
```

this mean 1 html page to get different page/image right?

i just need someone to point me to how to make it, 
or give me an example.

edit1:

using `<?echo $img;?>` in that way give me path/to/image/%3C?php%20echo%20$img;?%3E.jpg

iirc, the name of the image isn't `<?echo $img;?>.jpg`

Comment: You need to use a server-side programming language.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you can do it in php all you need to do is main.php?page=1

then in php you do

```
<?php 
 $img=$_GET['page'];
?>
<img src="path/to/image/<?php echo $img;?>.img_extension" />
```

Or you can use htaccess to rewrite your urls, in both cases you need server side scripting as @SLaks commented.

Comment: i was thinking js, but i guess i was wrong,
well, i know more about python than php,
 guess like this was a 'easy' problem FOR people who know php(not me) cause i got a down vote...

Comment: You can do it with js var x = window.location.toString(); then x_array=x.split('='); then the value you need is in x[1], then you use it. Can't say it is the best solution though

Comment: <?echo $img;?> doesn't seem to work, see question in a few mins after i edit it

Comment: it is <?php echo $img;?> not <?echo $img;?> and if it doesn't work then either your server doesn't support php or you're not setting the extension of the file to .php or many reasons all saying that where you're testing and how you're testing your php code is being treated as normal text.

Comment: with all the confusing tut about php with html and html with php on the internet... no wonder i was confuse about the 'echo every line'

Answer (score 0):

This part normally should be done on server side code by passing the url query parameter. However if you keen to have it on client side, you can try to use AngularJS to do it. I believe AngularJs pagnation part can do the similar logic.